# Canonical way to iterate with random-access iterator increments > 1?

Tags: c++, loops, iterator

We routinely iterate over containers with range-base for loop, or the pre-C++11 iterator based approach:

```
for(auto current = container.begin(); current != container.end(); ++current)
```

It is usually taught as a much preferred way over the "C-ish" iterations based on index increments:

```
for(auto currentId = 0; currentId != container.size(); ++currentId)
```

Yet, what if the requirement is to iterate every N *th* element, for example every third?

An **erroneous** rewrite of the above approach would give:

```
// Error
for(auto current = container.begin(); current != container.end(); current += 3)
```

Now, our programs exhibit undefined behaviour each time `(container.size() % 3) != 0`.

- What would be the canonical C++ way to address such requirement?
- Can it be done reasonably with iterator based iteration?
- Should we fall-back to indexes (with comparison becoming `<`instead of `!=`)?

Comment: `current != container.end()` => `std::distance(current, container.end()) >= 3`?

Comment: @cpplearner This is also a potential UB, as it would not prevent to increment `current` past the end iterator. Or as you wrote it, it would more likely skip the last valid element to iterate, since the check occurs each time before the `for` body.

Comment: `current != container.end()` => `std::distance(current, container.end()) < step_size` with `step_size` being 3 in the case shown.

Comment: @G.M. exact same problem as above: Since the condition is evaluated before the `for` body, your approach would miss the last "valid" element in the range. As long as current is a valid iterator, we need to execute the loop body on it, we don't care how far it is from the end. It might well be the last element.

Comment: @G.M. Also your condition is the other way around  ; )

Comment: @AdN Oh dear.  Not my finest hour :-)  I'll remove my comments in a few minutes since they're just noise.

Comment: @G.M. Don't worry, I'll keep the screen capture secret as long as you upvote the question  : )

Comment: A bit late but... if a range based loop is acceptable the [`boost.range`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/strided.html) allows you to use something like `for (auto &i: container | boost::adaptors::strided(3)) {` .